# Food prices during famines - Historical data

Tags: data-request, food

I'm looking for historical data regarding  local food prices during famines. I expect food prices to rise in order of magnitudes during famines but was unable to find reliable data.
I'm basically interested in the maximum price increase, could also be percentage. The historical period does not matter but the data should be accurate. Can sb. point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit: how distant of a history are you talking about? And do you mean *local* food prices (in which case the inflation seems rather agiven - no one wants to starve) or regional/worldwide?

Comment: I'm only interested in local prices. Historical timeframe does not matter